# Discord Python Rewrite - Mute "Role not found"

Tags: discord, discord.py

i was making a mute command, i want it to create the role if the role is not found. Here's my code

```
@client.command()
async def mute(ctx, member: discord.Member , time, *, reason):
    guild = ctx.guild

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == 'muted' or 'Muted':
            
            await member.add_roles(role)

            perms = channel.overwrites_for(member)
            perms.send_messages=False
            await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=perms, reason="Muted!")

            mutedembed = discord.Embed(
                title=f"Muted {member.name}",
                description="For the reason {}".format(reason),
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()
                )
            
            await ctx.send(embed=mutembed)

        else:
            perms = discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, read_messages=True)
            newRole = await guild.create_role(name="Muted", permissions=perms)

            await member.add_roles(newRole)
                
            mutedembed = discord.Embed(
                title=f"Muted {member.name}",
                description="For the reason {}".format(reason),
                timestamp=datetime.datetime.now()
                )

            await ctx.send(embed=mutembed)

            await asyncio.sleep(to_seconds(time))

            await member.role_remove(newRole)
            return
```

i want it to make the role if it's not on the role list, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [discord.utils.get](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=utils%20get#discord.utils.get)(guild.roles, name='Muted') to find if there is a muted role in the guild, and run your "else" case if not

Comment: From what I can see you basically have all the code you need, just get rid of your for loop and replace your if statement with the return from the discord.utils.get, as it will return None if there isn't a role called "Muted" in the server

Comment: like this?
`return role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Muted')`

Comment: Almost, I'm not gonna write your code for you buddy but just do `role = discord.utils.get(...)` then `if role:` <stuff if role exists> `else:` <stuff if role does not exist>